# Trouble updating records in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a website where I can upload articles however im having trouble with updating articles that have been created. I have managed to fill in a form with the information from the database pre-filled in but when i submit any changes then to the article then it does not update.

The $var_value is the primary key passed from the previous page to determine which article to load & edit.

Here is my form to update the article.

```
<?php   

        $var_value = $_POST['varname'];

        $get_studies = "select * from news where `news`.`articleID` = $var_value";

        $run_studies = mysqli_query($con,$get_studies);

        while($row_studies = mysqli_fetch_array($run_studies)){


            $newsTitle = $row_studies['title'];
            $newsDate = $row_studies['date'];
            $shortBio = $row_studies['shortBio'];
            $longBio = $row_studies['longBio'];
            $longBio2 = $row_studies['longBio2'];
            $image = $row_studies['image'];
        }

                echo "

                    <div class='panelContent1' id='addNewsWraper'>

                        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
                        <h3>Update Article</h3>

                        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit='alert('stop submit'); return false;' >

                            <div class='newsForm'>

                                <p>Article Title<br /><input type='text' value='$newsTitle' name='newsTitle' /></p>
                                <p>Short Description<br /><textarea name='newsShort' placeholder='Around a paragraph' />$shortBio</textarea>
                                <p>Image<br /><input type='file' name='newsImage' /></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='newsForm'>
                                <p>Date<br /><input type='text' value='$newsDate' name='newsDate' placeholder='2017' /></p>
                                <p>Story<br /><textarea name='newsLong' placeholder='News article text' />$longBio</textarea>
                                <p>Story2<br /><textarea name='newsLong2' value=''  placeholder='News article text' />$longBio2</textarea>


                                <button type='submit' name='updateNews'>
                                    Update
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>


                    </div>

                ";

            ?>
```

Here is how i am trying to update the article. I have tried to update the record based on a primary key, this variable is being passed to the page as its what is loading the content in the form.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['updateNews'])){


    $newsTitle = $_POST['newsTitle'];
    $newsDate = $_POST['newsDate'];
    $newsShort = $_POST['newsShort'];
    $newsLong = $_POST['newsLong'];
    $newsLong2 = $_POST['newsLong2'];
    $newsImage = $_POST['newsImage'];



$insertNews = "UPDATE mods SET title='$newsTitle', date='$newsDate', shortBio='$newsShort', longBio='$newsLong', longBio2='$newsLong2', image='$newsImage' WHERE articleID='$var_value'";

$updateNews = mysqli_query($con,$insertNews);

    if($updateNews){
        echo "<script>alert('Article updated.');</script>";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: `$newsImage = $_POST['newsImage'];` you're using the wrong superglobal.

Comment: and is unknown whether or not you did connect to your database; the 2nd part of your code doesn't show any evidence of that.

Comment: Hi Fred, I have connected to the database sorry I just added the code I used to try to update articles. Should I add more code for this then? The db connection is working fine though, the page loads the article i want to edit in the form from the database, just wont allow me to save the changes.

Comment: as I said in my first comment, `$newsImage = $_POST['newsImage'];` is incorrect, it should be `$_FILES` since we're dealing with "files" ;-) use error reporting and check for the real error in the query, if any. Using `mysqli_error($con)`.- to check for truthness, use `mysqli_affected_rows()` on UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks Fred I'll try that just now, im a still a novice with PHP SQL haha

Comment: welcome. Btw, `mysqli_affected_rows()` requires a connection passed as a single argument, consult the documentation on its usage.

Comment: Thanks Fred, much appreciated!

Comment: @Allan welcome. so did my first/second comment solve this? ping me with `@` ;-) since there is someone else in here now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry man still not got it working. -_- im having a read through seeing if i've made some typo etc.

Comment: Anything from php's error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and with `mysqli_error($con)` on the query. Put that in an `else{...}` against the `if($updateNews){
        echo "<script>alert('Article updated.');</script>";
    }`  but you should probably rename this `$updateNews = mysqli_query($con,$insertNews);` to `$updateNews2 = mysqli_query($con,$insertNews);` along with the related one below that. You're using the same variables, that could be playing tricks on you. Try removing the `onsubmit='alert('stop submit'); return false;'` also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm making progress. If i change the var for the primary key in the code for uploaded to the actual value of the key it works. really strange seeing it uses that variable to fill the content on the page. Anyway thanks for all of your help Fred!

Comment: Glad to see you're making progress. Keep at it, I'm sure you'll figure it out :-) If not, let me know and we can try to go to chat. I'm just not able to chat right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `$var_value` is being passed to your php update script, but I cannot see that is is, nor is it being picked up by a `POST` and transferred to a local variable. Pass it as a `<input type="hidden"` and then pick up with a `POST` to use.

In first php script:

```
<p>Article Title<br /><input type='text' value='$newsTitle' name='newsTitle' /> 
<input type="hidden" value='$var_value' name='var_value' />
</p>
```

In second php script:

```
 $var_value = $_POST['var_value'];
```

It would also be good to look at protecting your script from sql injection by using a parameterized query.

Comment: This is how i fixed it in the end. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your query

> `insertNews = "UPDATE mods SET title='$newsTitle' date='$newsDate' shortBio='$newsShort' longBio='$newsLong' longBio2='$newsLong2' image='$newsImage' WHERE articleID='$var_value'";`

Replace this with your current Query you will be good to go.